# How should I consolidate the output of many threads when it is variable-length?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I am implementing an OpenCL kernel, where each thread can potentially generate a varying amount of data. It's basically a radius searching function, hence each point can have a varying number of elements around it.

I could of course run it twice, once to figure out how many elements i need and allocate on the C++ code side, but that is a terrible way to do this. Is there a way I can so called "save" my state in my kernel code somewhere, exit, reallocate the resources needed to pull the data out, and have perhaps another kernel pull the data out?

Answer (score 2):

Some more suggestions:

1. If you know both of:

   - the maximum output size  per thread, and
   - the output size, or the max/min output size ratio, is not too high

   then it might make sense to just allocate the maximum possible output, and also make sure to write how much output space was actually used. Watch out for memory size limitations in that case though.
2. If you can bound the output size better over a workgroup rather than over a thread, you write output to workgroup-local memory and eventually/occasionally flush that to main memory (e.g. using atomics)

Also, regardless of what you choose to do, try to have each thread gather results in its own registers to the extent possible, so as to reduce the need for before triggering any conflicts/synchronization costs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to implement this robustly, you're going to need to have some kind of heuristic of determining "what is the maximum possible outputs my program could generate?". I don't know the details of your algorithm, so knowing how complex it is to determine that is beyond my ability. My advice is to find a "stripped down" version of your algorithm, whose only task is to assess, for each work item, "does this generate a solution? If so, atomically increment a global variable".

```
//Host Code
cl_mem mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 1 * sizeof(cl_long), nullptr, nullptr);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, /**/, sizeof(cl_mem), &mem);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(/*...*/);
cl_long num_of_solutions;
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, mem, true, 0, 1 * sizeof(cl_long), &num_of_solutions, nullptr, nullptr);
//Increase your memory on your final buffer to accomodate the number of solutions reported.

//Kernel Code
kernel void count_solutions(global long * num_of_solutions) {
    size_t id = get_global_id(0);
    /* Implementation is dependent on you, but 'get_number_of_generated_solutions'
     * would, ideally, get the number of generated solutions *without* the heavy lifting
     * associated with actually generating those solutions at all. But that's dependent on
     * whether that's actually possible for your specific algorithm.
     */
    int found_solutions = get_number_of_generated_solutions(id);
    //not sure if you need to explicitly enable 64-bit atomics or not
    atomic_add(num_of_solutions, found_solutions);
}
```

Then, allocate space based on that result.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state and re-create buffer but it would be slow if its going to be repeated.

Less memory needed, more overhead involved, but hideable by concurrent operations such as doing it in 4 steps(for each quarter of work area), one re-creating buffer, other running kernel, other uploading data, other downloading results.

---

You can have a max sized buffer and use its first element for counting total virtual allocations then calculate each workitem's own stack starting points using a prefix sum on GPU or simply scan with a cpu thread.

This would need multiple(logn) kernel steps for prefix sum part.

Better performance than re-creating buffers. Performance depends on elements distribution to boxes. Still unlimited allocation* per box.

---

You can give each workitem a fixed(non power of 2) range of elements, use their first element for counting, remaining ones for element(particle?) index saving.

This is faster than prefix sum version since atomic additions are done more locally (N particles per box for example) and doesn't need extra prefix sum operation.

No per-box allocation* flexibility, more stability in performance, could be fastest(for small number of elements per box such as 15).

---

Example of adding particles to boxes in a map where each box spans 4x4 pixels and map consists of 128x128 number of boxes (512x512 map)

```
int addParticleToBox(__global int * box, int boxIndex, int particleIndex)
{

    int newAllocIndex=atomic_add(&box[boxIndex*15],1/*size of index of element*/);

    if(nexAllocIndex<(15))
    box[boxIndex*15+newAllocIndex]=particleIndex;
}


__kernel void fillBoxes(__global int * box, __global float *x, __global float *y)
{
       int i=get_global_id(0);
       int boxX=floor(x[i])/4 ;
       int boxY=floor(y[i])/4 ;
       if(boxX>=0 && boxX< 128 && boxY>=0 && boxY<128)
       {
            int boxIndex=boxX+boxY*128;
            addParticleToBox(box,boxIndex,i/*particle index*/);
       }          
}
```

then when you need neighbouring particles, get box of a particle, get neighbour boxes of that box, read 0-index to know how many particles each one has, loop from 1 to n to get those neighbour particle indices.